# Is it possible my cream was too cold prior to whipping?

Tags: whipped-cream

I've whipped cream before. I recently bought whipping cream (a brand I'm not familiar with) and placed in the fridge prior to whipping. When I took it out of the box, it was a somewhat solid consistency (not liquid at all). So I tried whipping it and every time, it separates into curdle and liquid before even forming soft peaks.

Is the problem because the cream is solidified? instead of a liquified version where the air can encorporate. In this case, should I bring it outside first to see if it will liquify somewhat? Or should I just toss this container and buy my regular heavy cream instead.

Comment: I think it's bad.  Have a taste.  I've never seen whipping cream solidify at normal fridge temperatures.

Comment: Unless it's frozen, there's no really no such thing as too cold for whipping cream! Olga's suggestion that the solids rose to the top sound most likely, in which case you should be able to just fold them back together before whipping.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes whipping cream separates a little bit in the package and forms a solid layer on top of the liquid cream. This is normal and should not effect its whipping properties.

The few times I have had a hard time whipping cream has been on really hot days or when the cream doesnt contain enough fat. The cream has then separated in the same way as you described. Your cream should have about 40% fat.

You should easily be able to tell if the cream has gone off by smelling or tasting it.